# @Transactional and mappedBy Clash in Spring Unit/Integration Test

Tags: java, spring, persistence

I'm trying to write a test in Spring which happens to save and read back entities from a database multiple times. First I encountered a `LazyInitializationException`, but annotating the test with `@Transactional` solved that. Now, however, I'm facing the problem that the mappedBy-Relation of my data doesn't get updated in time - I read that this only happens at the end of the transaction.

The test as it stands is dependent on this relation to be updated - I'm testing for example that a bet can only be placed once per color and fails if it is attempted a second time. The code checking for already placed bets, however, is dependent on the bets field of the player.

How can I achieve this?

A simplified version of my data looks like:

```
@Entity
class Bet {
  @ManyToOne
  Player player;
  //...
}
@Entity
class Player {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="player")
  List<Bet> bets;
  //...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “_my data doesn't get updated in time_”? Do you mean that it is not flushed to the database? Are you trying to read the same data in another transaction?

Comment: I'm even trying to read the same data in the same transaction. I place a bet and as part of the test I place the same bet again to see if it fails (because a bet can only be placed once). Internally placing a bet tests the Player.bets field, though, and since it's all within one transaction the Player.bets is still empty when it's checked. What I'm trying to ask - I guess - is how can I split the test in multiple transactions while still avoiding the LazyInitializationException.

Comment: You have to update the collection yourself in that case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283654/adding-entity-doesnt-refresh-parents-collection

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Sort of. I changed a bunch of relationships to `FetchType.EAGER` and now the data is there in time and I don't get `LazyInitializationException` anymore. I'm not sure if this is costly in terms of performance, though. But I'm not sure I prefer your alternative. Since it's the goal of the test to check if the data is correct after some operations it seems to defeat the purpose of the test to put the correct data there manually.

Comment: I'm still not sure to understand what you are doing exactly. Could you show the (simplified) code of your test and your service?